# Upcasting a std::shared_ptr causes segfault

Tags: c++, c++11, smart-pointers

This is an oversimplification, but I cannot recreate the problem.

```
#include <memory>

class Base
{
};
class Derived : public Base
{
};

void doSomethingPolymorphical(std::shared_ptr<Base> basePointer)
{
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    std::shared_ptr<Derived> sharedObject = std::make_shared<Derived>();
    doSomethingPolymorphical(sharedObject);
    return 0;
}
```

The static checking finds no errors and this program executes fine. But in a more complicated program I get nondebuggable segfaults. I tried to change

```
std::shared_ptr<Derived> sharedObject = std::make_shared<Derived>();
```

for

```
std::shared_ptr<Base> sharedObject = std::make_shared<Derived>();
```

and the problem goes away.

I wanted to ask, if there are some issues with "upcasting" the `shared_ptr` that I am ignoring here, or if my segfaults come from elsewhere.

Comment: Upcasting *can't* be the issue here, since you do exactly that in the "changed" code too - just at an earlier place.

Comment: Have you tried emptying the virtual function ? Have you tried calling the virtual function from a non-virtual function in the base class ?

Comment: Is it possible you have multiple inheritance somewhere in your type hierarchy?

Comment: The nondebugable segfaults are symptomatic to undefined behavior in code that you did not post. Defect stops manifesting itself after little changes. it'll be back.

Comment: @J.N. actually this segfault is strange. When I try to find it with the debugger, I cannot see where the error exactly happened, so I do not know which virtual function to empty. When I try to find the error step by step. I get it when there is an attempt to initialize another std::shared_ptr<Base> by my "upcasted" std::shared_ptr<Derived>

Comment: Does your function actually take a *value type* (`std::shared_ptr<Base>`) or a *reference type* (`std::shared_ptr<Base> const&`)? In the latter case, the actual content may already be deleted, causing the issue.

Comment: (const std::shared_ptr<Base>&). You mean deleted by the smart_ptr (because the reference count == 0) or deleted by something else I am missing?

Comment: Now I changed it back to the original, but didn't get any segfault. It has to be somewhere else. Sorry for such a trash question and thank you for all your advices. I just really thought the problem is in the upcast.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the things to do would be to define virtual destructor in your base class, that way correct dtors will be called when shared_ptr goes out of scope

OTOH:
Seems like bug in VS2010, gcc 4.8 compiles & links okay

Following code fails to link with VS2010 with error:

1>Derived.obj : error LNK2005: "public: __thiscall Derived::Derived(void)" (??0Derived@@QAE@XZ) already defined in cpp.obj
1>Derived.obj : error LNK2005: "public: virtual __thiscall Derived::~Derived(void)" (??1Derived@@UAE@XZ) already defined in cpp.obj

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

class Base
{
public:

    Base()
    {}

    virtual ~Base()
    {}

    virtual void Print() const
    {
        std::cout << "from Base::Print" << std::endl;
    }
};

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    Derived() : Base()
    {}

    ~Derived()
    {}

    void Print() const
    {
        std::cout << "from Derived::Print" << std::endl;
    }
};

void doSomethingPolymorphical(std::shared_ptr<Base> basePointer)
{
    basePointer->Print();
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    std::shared_ptr<Derived> sharedObject = std::make_shared<Derived>();
    doSomethingPolymorphical(sharedObject);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why not use ```std::shared_ptr<Base> sharedObject = std::make_shared<Derived>();```

Comment: in this case you can use it. 
But if you make it bit more complicated where your instance shared_ptr<Derived> goes out of scope but you have another shared_ptr<Base> pointing to Derived*, then which destructor will be invoked? If you have instance-members then it is will lead to memory-corruption